# how to convert MSSQL Stored Procedure to Mysql SP using 'With' Keyword in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

this is my Stored Procedure of MSSQL and I want to be convert this SP to MySQL,but i cant understand what to used instead of 'with' keyword in MySql so any one help me ??? Thanx in Advance!!!!!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TPortRateOnKm_SP_List]
@qtype varchar(MAX) = NULL,
@query varchar(MAX)= NULL,
@Sortname varchar(MAX) =NULL,
@sortorder varchar(MAX) =NULL ,
@PageNo int,
@RecordsPerPage int,
@likesearch int
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @temp INT;
DECLARE @qry varchar(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @qry1 varchar(MAX) = '';
set @temp  = (@PageNo - 1) * @RecordsPerPage

If @query is not null and @query <> ''
Begin
Set @qry1= ' Where '+ @query    
End

Else
Begin 
Set @qry1= ''
End

If @query is not null and @query <> ''

Begin
Set @query= ' Where ('+ @query + ') and (RowNo > ' + 
            cast(((@PageNo-1) *@RecordsPerPage) as varchar) + '  AND RowNo <= '    
            + cast(@PageNo * @RecordsPerPage as varchar)+ ') '  
End

Else

Begin 
Set @query= ' Where (RowNo > ' + cast(((@PageNo-1) *@RecordsPerPage) as varchar) + '  AND RowNo <= ' + cast(@PageNo * @RecordsPerPage as varchar)+ ') '
End


If @sortorder is not null and @sortorder <> ''

Begin
Set @sortorder= ' Order By '+ @sortorder
End

Else

Begin 
Set @sortorder= ' ORDER BY VehicleId'
End
```

here is 'With' Keyword

```
set @qry = 'Set dateformat dmy ;WITH  CustomTable as
(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( '+ @sortorder+')  as RowNo,A.* From
(select Convert(varchar,T.WefDate,103) As WefDate,T.VehicleId as 
                VehicleId,V.VehicleNo as VehicleNo,T.StartKm,T.EndKm,T.Rate from 
                TrnRateOnKmRange T left outer join MasterVehicle V on             
                V.VehicleId=T.VehicleId) A '

   Set @qry= @qry + @qry1

   Set @qry= @qry + ' )

   SELECT CAST(RowNo AS INT) as 
               RowNo,WefDate,VehicleId,VehicleNo,StartKm,EndKm,Rate
   FROM CustomTable' 

   Set @qry=@qry +  @query + @sortorder

   EXECUTE (@qry)

               END
```

can any one do this ??

Comment: CTE (`WITH`) is not your only problem. MySQL also lacks support for windowing analytic functions (in your case `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...`)

Comment: 1) You can turn a CTE into a view or a subquery 2)you can use session variables or a subquery with `COUNT()` to emulate `ROW_NUMBER()`. In other words you have to start write your code and come with a very specific question.